# Replace light switch with smart switch, existing wiring used to be three way

Tags: electrical, lighting, switch, light, smart-switch

There is a light switch that controls some recessed lighting that I want to replace with a smart switch https://www.belkin.com/us/p/P-WLS040. The old light switch is a three way switch that is wired as single pole.

- There are two red wires for line and load on the old light switch.
- There is two black wires wire nutted together in the back of the receptacle.
- There is one white wire wire nutted by itself in the back of the receptacle.
- There is one white wire that is not stripped, just sitting by itself in the back of the receptacle.
- There are two ground wires twisted up together in the back of the receptacle.

Picture https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iau7V.jpg

I've tried tying the smart switch line with what I think is line, smart switch load with what I think is load, the smart switch neutral with the white wire nutted wire, and left smart switch ground wire nutted alone. When I flipped the circuit breaker back on, nothing happened. The smart switch didn't "turn on", and pressing the button on the switch didn't turn any lights on/off.

Do I need to strip the other white wire and tie all the white wires together?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4qKms.jpg Here is the other switches controlled by this circuit breaker. They are two single pole, the right one controls a hallway light and the left one controls porch lights.

Comment: Can you find the other boxes involved in this circuit and post photos of their innards please?

Comment: Try swapping the two red wires. You might have the line and load reversed and it will make a difference with a smart switch.

Comment: <https://imgur.com/a/7FKT491> Here is the other switches controlled by this circuit breaker. There are two single pole, the right one controls a hallway light and the left one controls porch lights.

Comment: @MeestaYeesta -- can you post photos of the inside of the box for the first recessed light controlled by the switch you're trying to replace then?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel you mean photos of the wiring of the recessed lights?

Comment: @MeestaYeesta yes